# Vim: How to show all completions instead of expanding to “self“ with omnicompletion in Python?

Tags: python, vim, python-3.x, omnicomplete

I don’t really need the “feature” of expanding to `self` when there are no beginning characters of the function/class/etc. specified yet, I’d rather have it show a list of all functions available in that context.

Is there a way to enable this somehow?

I’m afraid this is hard-coded in python3complete `(/usr/share/vim/vim73/autoload/python3complete.vim)`, in that case: Are there any changed version of that script?
(This is targeted at `python3`, but should be the same in `python2.x`, didn’t test it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the snipMate plugin? If you are, then there's probably a snippet that has the trigger ".", which will expand to "self.".

It looks something like this in a file called python.snippets:

```
snippet .
       self.
```

Remove those lines.

Comment: That’s it. Thanks. That’s what I get for copying stuff from others w/o looking through it. ;)

Comment: Oh, my, SnipMate is the work of a genious. I didn’t know what I missed without using it. oO Whoa.